# how to get JSON promises error status in my component ? ANGULAR - IONIC

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to print JSON result error in my front(component) so i cant get that.

My component has this function :

```
procesarDataWithEmail(val: any): void {

    let userTemp: any = {
      "email": val,
      "who_is":this.codeCategory,
      "latitude": this.lat,
      "longitude":this.lng
    };
    var loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Espere por favor...'
    });
    loading.present();
    console.log(userTemp);

    this._us.registerUser(userTemp).then(result => {

      this._us.registerProfesions(result,this.idSector,this.idProfesion).then((res) => {
        console.log("registerProfesions OK");
        console.log('>>>', res);
        loading.dismiss(true);
        this.presentAlertOK();
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
      }, (error: any) => {
        console.log("ERROR EN REGISTER USER-PROFESIONS"+error);
        loading.dismiss(true);
        this.presentAlertFail("Problema con el Servidor",'Inténtelo en breve. Gracias');
      });

    }, (error: any) => {
      console.log("ERROR EN REGISTER USER"+error);
      loading.dismiss(true);
      this.presentAlertFail('Email Incorrecto y/o registrado','Ingrese un email válido.Gracias');
    });
}
```

And in my service i has this :

```
registerUser(user: any) {
    //Registro:
    let url = URL_SERVICIOS + "/register";
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(user), options).subscribe((response: any) => {
        //JSON
        let js = response.json();

        let usuario = {
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password,
          id: js.result.id
        }
        resolve(usuario);
      }, (error: any) => {
        console.log("ERROR EN SERVICIO registerUser"+error);
        console.log("Response"+Response);
        reject(error);
        //en el reject te manda tambien cual fue el motivo
      })
    })
      /*
      .catch(err=>{
      console.log("ERROR CATCH");
      console.log(err);
    })*/
}
```

when in get error with reject i get this one :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RywC.jpg

And i would like to get this : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aShty.jpg

I've tried to put catch and it print well so I have 2 problems : 
1. I dont know how can i get this in my component 
2. If i use catch the next function is called

Comment: You can have the .catch part in your component where you subscribe to the response I think.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service suppose **Error** store the error there first pass it in the service **private error: Error** in in the service error one variable **data = null**

```
    (error: any) => {
            console.log("ERROR EN SERVICIO registerUser"+error);
this.error.data = error;
            console.log("Response"+Response);
            reject(error);
            //en el reject te manda tambien cual fue el motivo
          })
```

In the component inject Error component and

```
if (this.error.data){
localError = this.error.data;
}
```

Now you got it in component